# Converting this recursive function definition into nested sums?

Tags: recursion

Here's the recursive function I'm using:

```
DH[n_, k_, s_] := Sum[Binomial[k, k - j] DH[n/m^j, k - j, m + 1], {m, s, n^(1/k)}, {j, 1, k}]  
DH[n_, 0, s_] := 1
```

Now, on paper, if I expand out the recursion of DH by hand, I know that

```
DH[n,1,1] == n.
```

I also know, expanding by hand, that

```
DH[n,2,1] == 2 Sum[Floor[n/k], {k, 1, Floor[n^(1/2)]}] - Floor[n^(1/2)]^2
```

Can Mathematica do that for me, especially for larger values (like, say, `DH[n,8,1]` or `DH[n,10,2]`)?

I would like to type in `DH[n,2,1]` or `DH[n,3,1]` and get those sums, but right now, I just get a recursion depth exceeded error and no answers.

---

---

**The following is a note, not part of the original question**

Computing `DH[n,2,1]` by hand, For Mr. Wizard:

*Here's our starting formula*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Sum[Binomial[k, k - j] DH[n/m^j, k - j, m + 1], {m, s, n^(1/k)}, {j, 1, k}]
```

*apply `s=1, k=2` and remove the `{j,1,k} Sum` by manually looping `j` from `1 to k`, with `k=2`*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Sum[ Binomial[2,1] DH[ n/m, 2-1,m+1 ] + Binomial[2,2] DH[n/m^2, 2-2, m+1], 
   {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*apply binomials, simplify trivial arithmetic*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Sum[ 2 DH[n/m, 1,m+1] + DH[n/m^2,0,m+1], {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Swap in `DH[n,0,s] = 1`*

```
 DH[n,2,1] = Sum[ 2 DH[n/m, 1,m+1] + 1, {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Inspection should make clear that `DH[ n/m, 1, m+1 ] is Floor[n/m] - (m+1) + 1`*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Sum[ 2 (Floor[n/m]-m) + 1, {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Distribute the `x2`*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Sum[ 2 Floor[n/m] - 2 m + 1, {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Extract the `1` from the sum*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Floor[n^(1/2)] + Sum[ 2 Floor[n/m] - 2 m, {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Use the triangle number formula `(n)(n+1)/2` to pull `-2 m` out of the sum as `-2 ( Floor[n^(1/2)] (Floor[n^(1/2)] + 1))/2`*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Floor[n^(1/2)] -2 ( Floor[n^(1/2)] (Floor[n^(1/2)] + 1))/2 + Sum[ 2Floor[n/m], 
{m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Cancel the `2s` outside the sum, and move the `2` inside the sum out front*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Floor[n^(1/2)] - ( Floor[n^(1/2)] (Floor[n^(1/2)] + 1)) + 2 Sum[ Floor[n/m], 
{m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*Multiply the terms in parenthesis outside the sum*

```
DH[n,2,1] = Floor[n^(1/2)] - Floor[n^(1/2)]^2 - Floor[n^(1/2)] + 2 Sum[ Floor[n/m], 
   {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

*get rid of cancelling terms, and we are left with*

```
DH[n,2,1] = -Floor[n^(1/2)]^2 + 2 Sum[ Floor[n/m], {m,1,n^(1/2)}]
```

...which is what I wanted to show.  Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function and you should see that is indeed the equations for D(n) when using the hyperbola method.  That page mentions a generalized Divisor function, D_k(n).  The k in that function corresponds to the k here - this recursive expression applies the hyperbola method to D_k(n) for any k, a whole number.

By way of comparison, I have simplified `DH[x,4,2]` to

```
1 - Floor[x^(1/4)]^4 +
  Sum[
      4 (Floor[x/(u^3)] + Floor[Floor[x/u]^(1/3)]^3)
      - 6 Floor[ Floor[x/(u^2)]^(1/2)]^2 +
      12 (Sum [Floor[x/(u^2 s)], {s, (u + 1), 
  Floor[Floor[x/(u^2)]^(1/2)]}] +
      Sum[Floor[x/( u s^2)] - Floor[Floor[x/(u s)]^(1/2)]^2, {s, (u + 1),  
  Floor[Floor[x/u]^(1/3)]}]) +
      24  Sum[ Floor[x/(u m s)], {s, u + 1, (x/u)^(1/3)}, {m, s + 1, (x/(u s))^(1/2)}], 
  {u, 2, x^(1/4)}]
```

I haven't gotten up the gumption to go higher, as it's a bit exhausting to work through - thus my question.

Comment: Humor me; would you include an example of "expanding by hand" `DH[n,2,1]`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function DH is a tidy recursive way of expressing the Hyperbola method for the Dirichlet Divisor problem (if s=1).  DH[n,2,1] calculates D_2(n), from that link.

Comment: That's really going the extra mile for my curiosity.  Thank you!  I wish I could up-vote a second time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either

```
DH[n_, k_, s_] := 
  Sum[Sum[Binomial[k, k - j] DH[n/m^j, k - j, m + 1], {j, 1, k}], {m, s, n^(1/k)}]
```

or

```
DH[n_, k_, s_] := 
 Sum[Sum[Binomial[k, k - j] DH[n/m^j, k - j, m + 1], {m, s, n^(1/k)}], {j, 1, k}]
```

Then you get

```
DH[n, 1, 1]
(* n *)
```

and

```
DH[n, 2, 1]
(* -n + 2 n HarmonicNumber[Sqrt[n]] *)
```

in both cases.  However, the answer for `DH[n, 2, 1]` does not always agree with the answer you calculated by hand:

```
Table[-n + 2 n HarmonicNumber[Sqrt[n]] == 
        2 Sum[Floor[n/k], {k, 1, Floor[n^(1/2)]}] - Floor[n^(1/2)]^2,
      {n, 10}]
(* {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False} *)
```

I'll leave you to figure out whether the error is in the code or the calculation.

However, while *Mathematica* does reduce the double sum to a single sum for larger values, it does not succeed in reducing the sum `DH[n, 3, 1]` to closed-form, nor `DH[n, 8, 1]` (`DH[n, 10, 2]` ran for several minutes and I aborted it).  Perhaps someone else can help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Actually, if you put a Floor[] around n/m^j, the answer for DH[n,2,1] agrees with mine (except it's in a less simplified form), so that must've been the sticking point.  It's still hanging on DH[n,3,1], though.  But this gives me something to experiment with.